# Android studio not recognizing new module

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a project in android studio and we need to add a new module so my teammate added the module on a new a branch with some files in it and then I pulled the branch and now the new module is appearing in the file system and it's added to the settings.gradle but it's not recognized as a module in android studio , so how to make android studio recognize it as a module

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `settings.gradle` in this case should have a single `include` array formatted as (you might have had merge conflicts incorrectly handled to end up with double "include") :

```
include ':app', ':mobile'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new module in android studio with the same name , and it automatically had the files that was in the original module